# Driver for Canon PIXMA MG2200 scanner

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, canon

Does anyone have a driver for Canon MG2200 printer/scanner, since I can't seem to locate one.

Answer (score 0):

The printer and scanner drivers can be downloaded from Canon's [website](http://support-my.canon-asia.com/P/search?model=PIXMA%20MG2270&menu=download&filter=0&tagname=g_os&g_os=Linux) and installed in Ubuntu.

There you can find both the Printer and scanner drivers.  The file includes both the 32bit, and 64bit driver, make sure that you install the right one for your architecture.

Answer (score 0):

[MG2200 series ScanGear MP Ver. 2.00 for Linux (rpm Packagearchive)](http://support-my.canon-asia.com/contents/MY/EN/0100469601.html)

- Last Updated : 02-Nov-2012
- Issue Number : 0100469601

  **OS**: Linux
- This software is a scanner driver for Canon color image scanners.

Also see: [canon drivers](http://support-my.canon-asia.com/P/search?category=Inkjet%20Printers&series=PIXMA&model=PIXMA%20MG2270&menu=Download&filter=0) and [Install printer/scanner Canon PIXMA MG2270 in Ubuntu](http://waluyo-adi-siswanto.blogspot.de/2013/06/install-printerscanner-canon-pixma.html)